# Error rendering upload picture VichUploaderBundle [symfony2.8]

Tags: php, symfony, orm, twig, vichuploaderbundle

I'm using the Bundle VichUploader to upload a picture. The picture is well save in the web directory, but when i'm trying to render it, i have the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Undefined index: entity")

Config.yml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix:         /userprofile/pictures
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/flyplatform/userprofile/pictures
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     *
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
     *
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;



    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;

        if ($image) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $updatedAt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

PostType.php

```
$builder

    ->add('imageFile', 'vich_image', array(
    ))
```

new.html.twig

```
 {% for entity in entity %}
                                    <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'imageFile') }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" />
                                    {% endfor %}
```

**ADD:**

PostController.php

```
/**
     * Creates a new Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="post_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_USER")
     * @Template("FLYBookingsBundle:Post:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $user = $this->getUser();
        $entity = new Post();
        $entity->setEmail($user);
        $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class,$entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $usr = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container->get('security.context')
                ->getToken()
                ->getUser());
            $entity->setUsername($usr);

            $user = $this->getUser();
            $entity->setUser($user);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }



/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Post entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="post_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Post();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);



    return array( 'entity' => $entity,'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a purpose of looping through one item, so:

```
   {% for entity in entity %}
```

doesn't make a sense to me. What I noramlly do when I have a set of entities:

```
   {% for entity in entities %}
```

With entities is an array of objects passed to the template.
What is the code of your controller? so that we can see the parameters you pass to the template. what does `product` refer to?

What is the line of code throwing the error?

Comment: This is the line of code that throwing the error: `  {% for entity in entity %}
                                    <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'imageFile') }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" />
                                    {% endfor %}`.  I added my controller on my post on top.

Comment: Even `{% for entity in entity %}` can be syntaxically correct, it has no sense. Why to loop through one item? Do you see my answer?

Comment: ok, as i have to render only one picture i don't need to loop. So i should try something like this :  `<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'imageFile') }}" alt="{{entity.imageName }}" />` ?

Comment: yes you are right, but `entity` and `product` should be provided to the view in controller. I am still waiting for your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a way to fix my issue. When i inspect the element i noticed that the path to the image is like this : `/userprofile/pictures` , but actually it should be like this:`/symfony/web/bundles/flyplatform/userprofile/pictures/`. i changed the `uri_prefix: /userprofile/pictures` to this one `uri_prefix: /symfony/web/bundles/flyplatform/userprofile/pictures/`

```
<img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'imageFile') }}" alt="{{entity.imageName }}" />
```

.

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: /symfony/web/bundles/flyplatform/userprofile/pictures/
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles/flyplatform/userprofile/pictures
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
            inject_on_load:     false
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true
```

i hope this will help someone in the future.